# Can't figure out memory usage of process

Tags: c#

I'm trying to ensure that a given block of code does not use excessive memory. I'm reading the currently used memory with PeakWorkingSet64() before the code block and after. But the value reported is the same. What is wrong?

```
    private static void memTest()
    {
        Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        long memBefore = p.PeakWorkingSet64 / 1000;
        List<string> l = new List<string>();
        int cnt = 0;
        try { while (true) { l.Add("Hello World"); cnt++; } }
        catch { }
        long memAfter = p.PeakWorkingSet64 / 1000;
        Console.WriteLine("memBefore={0} memAfter={1} cnt={2}", memBefore, memAfter, cnt);
    }
```

Comment: I think you will need to re-get the current process for the new stats.

Comment: Doing this in the process that your checking will scew your results because the Process object has a lot of overhead.  Ideally you should be monitoring your process with another process.  RedGate makes a tool for this and it might have a trial, The Ants Memory Profiler. http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/

Comment: Also, see if there is anything on the MSDN for it that will help you out on this page, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9z62c29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You should add following line before getting the PeakWorkingSet64 property again:

```
p.Refresh();
```

The reason is described as follow by MSDN:

> When a Process component is associated with a process resource, the
>   property values of the Process are immediately populated according to
>   the status of the associated process. If the information about the
>   associated process subsequently changes, those changes are not
>   reflected in the Process component's cached values. The Process
>   component is a snapshot of the process resource at the time they are
>   associated. To view the current values for the associated process,
>   call the Refresh method.

See the [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.refresh(v=vs.100).aspx) for further details.